# Replace each fruits and animals with numbers and operators

Tags: mathematics, visual, number-theory

Replace each fruit with numbers 5 to 10.
Replace each animal with operators $[+,-,×,/]$.
So all the math operations vertically and Horizontally correct.
Ignore BODMA rule (order of operations DO NOT matter)

[image]

Comment: DOes the number of fruits matter? Like for each banana, there is a number or is it for the whole bunch of bananas?

Comment: @Sid No, it is for the whole bunch of bananas

Comment: And does each number correspond to a unique animal? Or can two animals have the same number?

Comment: @Sid each number correspond to a unique fruit, each animal correspond to a unique operator.

Comment: Hey, do order of operations matter?

Comment: @Wen1now No, ignore the rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two solutions.

> ```
>  7 - 6 + 5 = 6
>  -   /   *
>  8 - 6 + 8 = 10
>  +   *   /
>  9 / 9 * 5 = 5
>  =   =   =
>  8   9   8
>  
>  8 - 9 +10 = 9
>  -   /   *
>  7 - 9 + 7 = 5
>  +   *   /
>  6 / 6 *10 = 10
>  =   =   =
>  7   6   7
> ```

My working:

> The second and third column, and the third row, suggest that butterfly/rabbit are inverse operations. If you choose them to be addition/subtraction, you soon find the other equations to be  impossible - the numbers 5-10 are too restrictive in their factors to make it work. Therefore, butterfly/rabbit are divide/multiply and obviously in that order.
>
> If the chicken were addition, lion subtraction, you soon need some duplicate numbers for the fruits, so chicken is subtraction, lion addition.
>
> The equations of the first column and the second row now give you that two bunches of berries(?) equals lychee+pineapple and also equals cherry(?)+banana. This means that the berries must be 7 (with 6+8 and 5+9, leaving the lemon as 10) or 8 (with 7+9 and 6+10, leaving the lemon as 5). In either case, the first row equation determines how the four paired numbers are placed for the other fruits.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I got:

> Banana=6
>  3 Leaf-type thing=8
>  Pineapple=7
>  Moon-like thing=9
>  Lemon=5
>  Brown thing=10

And the animals:

> Lion=+
>  Hen=-
>  Butterfly=/
>  Rabbit=*

Answer (score 2):

So..

Let's start -

> 1. Take the first row, and get all the bigger numbers in -
>  [image]
>
>  2. Then, take the 1st vertical row and get the next big number in - 
>  [image]
>
>  3. Now, it's just the matter for filling the things we have -
>  [image]
>
>  4. It can be easily seen than the remaining operations / and * can be used now
>  [image]